# Disable runtime error dialog in Android (titanium)

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile

Is there any way to configure the titanium android such that it won't show runtime error dialog to users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn't right now. There may be in the future, though. Chime in on this ticket if it's something you still want:

https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-9735

Comment: Also note that in the ticket, I've provided links to the points in Titanium Mobile's source that handle the error dialogs. So you can either a) hack the source for yourself and get around this temporarily, or b) hack the source for everyone and submit a pull request with the proper behavior. "a" is quick. "b" is better. ;)

Comment: Thanks Daw! I think I will go for 'a' for now.