# Titanium Runtime Error Dialog in Android

Tags: dialog, runtime, titanium, distribution, appcelerator

This is a question for Titanium developers. When you run your application and a Exception is thrown, you get a Runtime Error dialog. This is nice to debug, but the problem is that when you build the application to distribute in Google Play it still shows this dialog.
Is there any way to disable it? So if application crashes the user just get standard Android error message.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This has been disabled for production deployments with the latest versions of the Titanium SDK: https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-9735

You've also duplicated a prior question with nearly the same title: [Disable runtime error dialog in Android (titanium)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10827463/disable-runtime-error-dialog-in-android-titanium/11165347#11165347)